# ISBLANK for checking multiple cells for any data and then using that data in my cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following scenario:
I have drop down menus on another tab for people to select from several types of screw. There are 6 different cells that could contain some data. It should never be the same data in any two cells. But I need to have my cell on my front page go and look at those 6 cells and see if there are any cells that are NON-BLANK and once data is found in a cell to copy that to the cell I am working from. Can I use the ISBLANK formula to nest and look at multiple cells for data? Or is there a better way?

To be more clear, what I want the formula to do is to look at cell T34 and if it has data then stop and copy that data. But if cell T34 is blank I want the formula to move on to T35 and see if it is blank or not...repeating the process until it finds data in one of the 6 cells that the user inputs their data. Once data is found I want it copied to the cell where the formula is located.

Comment: To be more clear, what I want the formula to do is to look at cell T34 and if it has data then stop and copy that data. But if cell T34 is blank I want the formula to move on to T35 and see if it is blank or not...repeating the process until it finds data in one of the 6 cells that the user inputs their data. Once data is found I want it copied to the cell where the formula is located.

Comment: You should [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1483550/edit) instead of adding information like this in comments

Answer (score 2):

You can nest the `IF`s:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(T35),IF(ISBLANK(T36),IF(ISBLANK(T37),IF(ISBLANK(T38),IF(ISBLANK(T39),IF(ISBLANK(T40),"",T40),T39),T38),T37),T36),T35)
```

And a more elegant solution using an array formula:

```
 {=IFERROR(INDEX(T35:T40,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(T35:T40),0)),"")}
```

(must be confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>)